# Compile OpenCV with CUDA support on OSX

Tags: opencv, opencv3.0

I'm trying to compile opencv 3.4 with CUDA support on OSX. CUDA is installed and works fine, but `make` gives me an error. I issue the following options with `cmake`:

```
cmake -DBUILD_TIFF=ON -DBUILD_opencv_java=OFF \
-DWITH_CUDA=ON -DWITH_OPENGL=ON -DWITH_OPENCL=ON \
-DWITH_IPP=ON -DWITH_TBB=ON -DWITH_EIGEN=ON \
-DWITH_V4L=ON -DWITH_VTK=OFF -DBUILD_TESTS=OFF \
-DBUILD_PERF_TESTS=OFF -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=RELEASE \
-DPYTHON3_EXECUTABLE=~/Projects/rtmp-test/bin/python \
-DPYTHON3_PACKAGES_PATH=~/Projects/rtmp-test/lib/python3.8/site-packages/ \
-DPYTHON_NUMPY_INCLUDE_DIRS=~/Projects/rtmp-test/lib/python3.8/site-packages/numpy/core/include/numpy \
-DOPENCV_EXTRA_MODULES_PATH=~/Projects/opencv-cuda/opencv_contrib/modules ..
```

But when I run `make`, I get the following error:

```
[ 44%] Linking CXX static library ../lib/liblibprotobuf.a
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/ranlib: 
file: ../lib/liblibprotobuf.a(atomicops_internals_x86_gcc.cc.o) has no symbols
```

I [read here](https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-science/issues/5819) that it could be because nvcc doesn't support clang 8.1.0 and I'm on Xcode 9.2. Anyone know how this can be resolved?

Any thought appreciated.